# AVFoundation - Export and multi-pass encoding not very optimized?

Tags: ios, macos, avfoundation, core-media

- I am using AVFoundation to re-export a video. I am reading it in using AVAssetReader, and then exporting again using AVAssetWriter. Works great for "normal" videos.
- However, I've noticed that for videos where everything is constant except for a small region (e.g: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VyhG-AKLK-Y) it doesn't compress very well.
- The reason is probably that the encoder has no way of knowing the contents of the video so it uses a generic compression method.
- I came across this: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/513/ and implemented the steps needed to support multi-pass encoding (uses an additional pass so that it can analyze the contents of the video first).
- The results, while better than the default, doesn't match up to ffmpeg or videos exported from premiere (much worse quality with higher filesize).

Does anyone have any insights on how to best optimize for videos like this?

Comment: You should compare the bit rate, key framing, reordering, codec profile & level, etc you're encoding with in AVF and ffmpeg. ffmpeg supports more strategies for compression, so AVF simply can't match those, but at the least when using the same settings they should produce very similar results.